# How to match strings between two columns in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, match, character

I want to create a new column (MATCH) on the basis of string match between two existing columns. For example -

| st_add | aa_add | MATCH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jai maa durga society | jai maa durga colony | MATCH |
| elph road highway 1 | road highway 2 elph | MATCH |
| srinivan colony parel ist | srinivan bus depot | NOT MATCH |

If there is a match in three or more words between column 1 and column 2 then then column 3(MATCH) should show "MATCH". But if there is less than 3 words matches or no match at all (example row 3) then the result should be "NO MATCH"

How can I do this using R??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the data into words in `st_add` and `aa_add` count the number of common words, if they are greater than equal to 3 assign `'MATCH'` to it.

```
df$MATCH <- ifelse(mapply(function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)), 
                strsplit(df$st_add, '\\s+'),
                strsplit(df$aa_add, '\\s+')) >= 3, 'MATCH', 'NOT MATCH')
df

#                     st_add               aa_add     MATCH
#1     jai maa durga society jai maa durga colony     MATCH
#2       elph road highway 1  road highway 2 elph     MATCH
#3 srinivan colony parel ist   srinivan bus depot NOT MATCH
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(st_add = c("jai maa durga society", "elph road highway 1", 
"srinivan colony parel ist"), aa_add = c("jai maa durga colony", 
"road highway 2 elph", "srinivan bus depot")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `stringdist`. You can set a string distance threshold for a match. It also offers multiple methods for computing distance. Thanks Ronak for the dataset code.

```
library(stringdist)

df$match <- ifelse(stringdist(df$st_add, df$aa_add) < 12, "MATCH", "NOT MATCH")
df

#                      st_add               aa_add     match
# 1     jai maa durga society jai maa durga colony     MATCH
# 2       elph road highway 1  road highway 2 elph     MATCH
# 3 srinivan colony parel ist   srinivan bus depot NOT MATCH
```